Capture serial port data and plot with xplot
I am trying to capture csv data from the serial port and plot with xplot, but the script just hangs and no temp file is created.
#!/bin/bash

# Set the serial port
port="/dev/ttyACM0"

# Set the baud rate
baudrate=115200

# Set the number of data points to plot
num_points=10

# Create a temporary file to store the data
tempfile=$(mktemp)

# Function to read data from serial port
read_serial_data() {
  stty -F "$port" raw -echo cs8 115200 clocal ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig icanon iexten echo
  exec < "$port"
  for ((i=0; i<num_points; i++)); do
    read -r line
    echo "$line" >> "$tempfile"
  done
  stty -F "$port" sane
}

# Read data from serial port
read_serial_data

# Extract x and y values from CSV data
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' "$tempfile" > data.txt

# Plot the data using xplot
xplot -p data.txt

# Clean up temporary files
rm "$tempfile" data.txt

Any help would be very much appreciated.

`$ shellcheck myscript
Line 7:
baudrate=115200
^-- SC2034 (warning): baudrate appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).`

It makes no diff. and I have no such "spellcheck".

I added echos in between functions to see the point that the script won't pass and it's stuck without an error or warning on the read_serial_data function.

Your termios configuration for the serial terminal using the stty command is nonsensical. It specifies both raw and icanon, which is contradictory . You neglect to clearly describe what the data you expect to read actually looks like, so who knows what the proper configuration is? BTW the serial terminal should be initialized only one time using the stty command, and not (repeatedly) before & after each "read". The "read" merely fetches data from a system buffer, and is not at all synchronized with actual serial port activity.

@Richard the [tag:bash] tag you used provides a link to shellcheck (not spellcheck): "NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about."
